# IGMP V3 support in Linux-2.6.35

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, multicast, igmp

I am trying to start a bridge connection and force it to use IGMPV3.

The following command will explain my issue better :

The below is the output of force_igmp_version before issuing brctl commands

```
/ # cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/br/force_igmp_version
3
/ # cat /proc/net/igmp
Idx     Device    : Count Querier       Group    Users Timer    Reporter
1       lo        :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
3       eth0      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
4       eth1      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
5       eth2      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
```

Then I issue a set of brctl command to add a bridge and add my eth0 and eth1 interface to the bridge and do ifconfig on the bridge. But surprisingly bridge created is still using IGMPV2.

```
/ # cat /proc/net/igmp
Idx     Device    : Count Querier       Group    Users Timer    Reporter
1       lo        :     1      V3
                         E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
3       eth0      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
4       eth1      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
5       eth2      :     1      V3
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
6       br        :     1      V2
                        E0000001     1 0:00000000               0
```

Is there anything I am missing to configure to make the bridge start with IGMPV3?

How can I force the bridge to use IGMPV3?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into this issue myself. So far i have found only that IGMPv3 is not supported in bridge, or at least not supported in all versions of linux kernel. I would try to dissable IGMP Snooping in bridge. I expect that then IGMPv3 packets will be sent.